# Connecting Remote Cassandra(1.2.1) Server

Tags: windows, cassandra

I am running Cassandra 1.2.1 on a remote Windows server. I set the yaml settings as following;

rpc_address: 0.0.0.0 
start_native_transport: true

**I can** connect the remote Cassandra server from my laptop by typing the IP address and port number;

connect XXX.XX.XX.XX/9160;

on cassandra-cli.bat

**But I can not** connect the remote Cassandra server from my .Net Application. I use *casssandra-sharp*;

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
using (ICluster cluster = ClusterManager.GetCluster("main"))
          Console.WriteLine("succeded");
ClusterManager.Shutdown();
```

Here is the App.config;

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="CassandraSharp" type="CassandraSharp.SectionHandler, CassandraSharp" />
  </configSections>

  <CassandraSharp>
    <Cluster name="main">
      <Endpoints>
        <Server>XXX.XX.XX.XX</Server>
      </Endpoints>
    </Cluster>
  </CassandraSharp>
```

The application throws "Can't find any valid endpoint" exception. When I run Cassandra locally and try to connect, this code block perfectly works.

On remote server 9160 and 7000 ports are allowed on firewall. Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@rs_atl is right, it is a connectivity issue.

If you are using a client library and going to execute CQL commands, you need to set;

```
start_native_transport: true
```

which you already did. Just two lines below, you will see;

```
native_transport_port: 9042
```

in yaml file. That means you need to allow port number **9042** on firewall.

*If you also using a cloud service like Azure do not forget to add an End Point.*

Answer (score 0):

If your code works locally but does not work on another machine, the only logical conclusion is there must be a connectivity issue.